# Displaying characters on screen, using assembly

Tags: assembly, command-prompt

I´ve been having a really hard time trying to make this code work, this is my first time using assembly. I used NASM to create a .com file without any errors but still no character are displayed, using AFD for debugging i realize that everything works but this line mov   word [es:di], 0x0720, this is suposse to display a space on the direction di is pointing at, but it is not displayed, i have tried changing 0x0720 for the code of somenthing other than a space but still no character is shown.

```
[org 0x100]
                mov ax, 0xb800
                mov es, ax
                mov di, 0

nextchar:       mov   word [es:di], 0x0720
                add   di, 2
                cmp   di, 4000
                jne   nextchar

        mov ax, 0x4c00
        int 0x21
```

Comment: What is AFD - a DOS emulator? - does it have a color video adapter defined?

Comment: advance full screen debugger, not sure what a dos emulator is, i used to run the .com files step by step, anyway using text mode as suggested by michael made it work

Comment: were you using DOSBOX or simple windows console/cmd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a [suitable video mode](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) first. For example:

```
mov ax,0x0003  ; 80x25 text mode, 16 colors
int 0x10
```